# Model binding and default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How to pass a default value to a model bound input? its not working

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { @class="ctype", value="default city"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in the controller action rendering this view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SomeViewModel model = ...
    model.City = "default value";
    return View(model);
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "ctype" })
```

or if you want to use the [HTML5 placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute you could do the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "ctype", placeholder = "default value" })
```

or if you use a weakly typed helper (absolutely not recommended):

```
@Html.TextBox("City", "default value", new { @class = "ctype" })
```